# My update query doesn't work on database

Tags: asp.net, authentication, sql-update

I wrote this code in my login page. My code doesn't any error but update query doesn't apply on my database.
Fist query works and I redirect to `index.aspx` but update query (second query) doesn't apply!!!!

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database db1 = new Database();
        string query = "select * from Admins where UserName=@username and cast(Password as varbinary)=cast(@password as varbinary)";
        SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand(query, db1.sc);
        smd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
        smd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", General.CreatePasswordHash(txtPassword.Text));
        SqlDataReader sdr = smd.ExecuteReader();
        smd.Parameters.Clear();
        if (sdr.Read())
        {
            Session.Add("username", sdr[0].ToString());
            string nowEnter = sdr[5].ToString();
            query = "update Admins set LastEnter=@lastEnter, NowEnter=@nowEnter where UserName=@username";
            string now = General.getPersianDateNow() + " ساعت " + General.getPersianTimeNow();
            smd.CommandText = query;
            smd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastEnter", nowEnter);
            smd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nowEnter", now);
            smd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", sdr[1].ToString());
            sdr.Close();
            smd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("~/admin/Index.aspx", false);
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Visible = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing smd.ExecuteNonQuery() twice?

Comment: You are getting username for the session from `sdr[0]`, but for the SQL parameters you take it from `sdr[1]`. Is it in both elements of the reader?

Comment: @Melanie : That `int id=smd.ExecuteNonQuery()` is for trace. I delete it.

Comment: @davmos: Thanks a lot. Now my code works correctly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the problem is with index of `sdr`. First one you invoke

```
Session.Add("username", sdr[0].ToString());
```

Two lines below you use

```
 smd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", sdr[1].ToString());
```

Anyway the safest way is to create select statement with named colums instead of using `*`

Comment: Spotted that too and commented. Up-voting this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that the value you are using for the username exists in the table.

You're also adding the same parameter twice. I don't know how the SqlCommand class will handle that and I can't test it right now, but I think it might be a good idea to clear your parameters (`smd.Parameters.Clear()`) between executions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it at first. My bad.